# Ubuntu 22.04 no longer boots reliably

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I have been running Ubuntu on my NUC10i7FNH system for several years with no problems. Upgraded Ubuntu to 22.04 months ago; no problems. Recently, though, booting the system results in screen flashing between black and Signal-lost for as long as I can take it.
It eventually boots for no repeatable reason I can see; I've tried ctl-alt-del, esc, various function key, etc. Floundering. Sometimes gets to GRUB then boots, sometimes boots clean offering choice of F2, F7, F10 to proceed.  F10 boots it, then. I added a USB drive with Linux Mint 18.1 autoboot and it seems more willing, though still with black screen/signal-lost alterations from which ctl-alt-delete eventually gets to the boot screen and my Ubuntu 22.04 via a menu offered selection, not to Mint. Not trying to use Mint, just seeing if anything else will boot per boot order: USB first.
Once booted Ubuntu runs with no problems till I turn it off.  This system has 32GB Ram and two TB SSD drives, all mostly empty. I am essentially a wanabe scriptkiddy and know too little to figure this out.  What have I screwed up? Help appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever checked the memory?  Try swapping the memory sticks to see if any difference.

Comment: Why are you trying with a non Ubuntu version of Linux to figure out what is wrong with this Ubuntu install?

Answer (score 1):

Intermittent video failure suggests a hardware fault unrelated to the OS.

Try a different video cable. Try a different monitor. Try a different NUC.

Replacing the correct one of those three usually fixes such problems.